# Excel Formatting table2excel.js

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I am using table2excel.js for export HTML to Excel and it is working fine. I want to change row or column color as per condition. Is it possible?

```
    <table id="ExcelTable" style="text-align: left;display:none">
    <tr class="rpthide">
        <td class="Supplier" style="font-size:14px;"></td>
        <td class="ContractNo" style="font-size:14px;"></td>
        <td class="OrderNo" style="font-size:14px;"></td>
        <td class="Article" style="font-size:14px;"></td>
        <td class="Ordered" style="font-size:14px;"></td>
        <td class="ContainerNo" style="font-size:14px;"></td>
        <td class="ETA" style="font-size:14px;"></td>
        <td class="Dispatched" style="font-size:14px;"></td>
        <td class="AtPort" style="font-size:14px;"></td>
        <td class="Arrived" style="font-size:14px;"></td>

    </tr>
</table>

$("#ExcelTable").table2excel({
              // exclude CSS class
              exclude: ".noExl",
              name: "Yarn Status List",
              filename: "Yarn Status List" //do not include extension
          });
```

Comment: Can you provide code showing what you have come up with so far?

Comment: whats your version of office excel? i can't open generated file in my pc

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use better tools like as [ExcellentExport.js](https://github.com/jmaister/excellentexport) 
you can apply any css style to the html table, and they will be exported at the output.

Sample Usage:

```
<script src="excellentexport.js"></script>

<table id="ExcelTable">
  <tr>
    <td style="color:red">Column 1</td>
    <td style="color:blue">Column 2</td>
    <td style="color:green; font-weight:bold">Column 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color: purple">
    <td>400</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td>600</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<a download="myFile.xls" href="#" onclick="return ExcellentExport.excel(this, 'ExcelTable', 'Sheet1');">Export to Excel</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

use span tag in td.
Ex: `<td> <span style="color:red">6000</span> </td>`

its work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

make preserveFont:true to use font-size and font-weight

```js
 $(function () {
        $("#exportexcel").click(function () {
            var $table = $('.table2excel');
            $table.removeData(); //data is removed, previous when data existed was preventing initialization of table2excel

            $table.table2excel({
                exclude: ".noExl",
                sheetName: "Demo_Report",
                filename: "demo_Report",
                fileext: ".xls",
                preserveFont:true,
            });
        });
    });
```

yes you can to change color you should use PreserveColor:true option which has given in table2excel github repo and for font-size and font-weight I have make changes in main file below Iam sharing you my table2excel raw code and PreserveFont option is made by me so you can use it .it get you fontsize and font-weight from your table

```js
/*
 *  jQuery table2excel - v1.1.2
 *  jQuery plugin to export an .xls file in browser from an HTML table
 *  https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel
 *
 *  Made by rainabba
 *  Under MIT License
 */
//table2excel.js
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    var pluginName = "table2excel",

        defaults = {
            exclude: ".noExl",
            name: "Table2Excel",
            filename: "table2excel",
            fileext: ".xls",
            exclude_img: true,
            exclude_links: true,
            exclude_inputs: true,
            preserveColors: false
        };

    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Plugin(element, options) {
        this.element = element;
        // jQuery has an extend method which merges the contents of two or
        // more objects, storing the result in the first object. The first object
        // is generally empty as we don't want to alter the default options for
        // future instances of the plugin
        //
        this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {
        init: function () {
            var e = this;

            var utf8Heading = "<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8\">";
            e.template = {
                head: "<html xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\">" + utf8Heading + "<head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets>",
                sheet: {
                    head: "<x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>",
                    tail: "</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>"
                },
                mid: "</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body>",
                table: {
                    head: "<table>",
                    tail: "</table>"
                },
                foot: "</body></html>"
            };

            e.tableRows = [];

            // Styling variables
            var additionalStyles = "";
            var compStyle = null;

            // get contents of table except for exclude
            $(e.element).each(function (i, o) {
                var tempRows = "";
                $(o).find("tr").not(e.settings.exclude).each(function (i, p) {

                    // Reset for this row
                    additionalStyles = "";

                    // Preserve background and text colors on the row
                    if (e.settings.preserveColors) {
                        compStyle = getComputedStyle(p);
                        additionalStyles += (compStyle && compStyle.backgroundColor ? "background-color: " + compStyle.backgroundColor + ";" : "");
                        additionalStyles += (compStyle && compStyle.color ? "color: " + compStyle.color + ";" : "");
                    }
                    
                    // Create HTML for Row
                    tempRows += "<tr style='" + additionalStyles + "'>";

                    // Loop through each TH and TD
                    $(p).find("td,th").not(e.settings.exclude).each(function (i, q) { // p did not exist, I corrected

                        // Reset for this column
                        additionalStyles = "";

                        // Preserve background and text colors on the row
                        if (e.settings.preserveColors) {
                            compStyle = getComputedStyle(q);
                            additionalStyles += (compStyle && compStyle.backgroundColor ? "background-color: " + compStyle.backgroundColor + ";" : "");
                            additionalStyles += (compStyle && compStyle.color ? "color: " + compStyle.color + ";" : "");
                        }
                        if (e.settings.preserveFont) {
                            compStyle = getComputedStyle(q);
                            additionalStyles += (compStyle && compStyle.fontSize ? "font-size : " + compStyle.fontSize + ";" : "");
                            additionalStyles += (compStyle && compStyle.fontWeight ? "font-weight : " + compStyle.fontWeight + ";" : "");
                        }

                        var rc = {
                            rows: $(this).attr("rowspan"),
                            cols: $(this).attr("colspan"),
                            flag: $(q).find(e.settings.exclude)
                        };

                        if (rc.flag.length > 0) {
                            tempRows += "<td> </td>"; // exclude it!!
                        } else {
                            tempRows += "<td";
                            if (rc.rows > 0) {
                                tempRows += " rowspan='" + rc.rows + "' ";
                            }
                            if (rc.cols > 0) {
                                tempRows += " colspan='" + rc.cols + "' ";
                            }
                            if (additionalStyles) {
                                tempRows += " style='" + additionalStyles + "'";
                            }
                            tempRows += ">" + $(q).html() + "</td>";
                        }
                    });

                    tempRows += "</tr>";

                });
                // exclude img tags
                if (e.settings.exclude_img) {
                    tempRows = exclude_img(tempRows);
                }

                // exclude link tags
                if (e.settings.exclude_links) {
                    tempRows = exclude_links(tempRows);
                }

                // exclude input tags
                if (e.settings.exclude_inputs) {
                    tempRows = exclude_inputs(tempRows);
                }
                e.tableRows.push(tempRows);
            });

            e.tableToExcel(e.tableRows, e.settings.name, e.settings.sheetName);
        },

        tableToExcel: function (table, name, sheetName) {
            var e = this, fullTemplate = "", i, link, a;

            e.format = function (s, c) {
                return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
                    return c[p];
                });
            };

            sheetName = typeof sheetName === "undefined" ? "Sheet" : sheetName;

            e.ctx = {
                worksheet: name || "Worksheet",
                table: table,
                sheetName: sheetName
            };

            fullTemplate = e.template.head;

            if ($.isArray(table)) {
                Object.keys(table).forEach(function (i) {
                    //fullTemplate += e.template.sheet.head + "{worksheet" + i + "}" + e.template.sheet.tail;
                    fullTemplate += e.template.sheet.head + sheetName + i + e.template.sheet.tail;
                });
            }

            fullTemplate += e.template.mid;

            if ($.isArray(table)) {
                Object.keys(table).forEach(function (i) {
                    fullTemplate += e.template.table.head + "{table" + i + "}" + e.template.table.tail;
                });
            }

            fullTemplate += e.template.foot;

            for (i in table) {
                e.ctx["table" + i] = table[i];
            }
            delete e.ctx.table;

            var isIE = navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 10") !== -1 || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident") !== -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf("rv:11") !== -1); // this works with IE10 and IE11 both :)
            //if (typeof msie !== "undefined" && msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // this works ONLY with IE 11!!!
            if (isIE) {
                if (typeof Blob !== "undefined") {
                    //use blobs if we can
                    fullTemplate = e.format(fullTemplate, e.ctx); // with this, works with IE
                    fullTemplate = [fullTemplate];
                    //convert to array
                    var blob1 = new Blob(fullTemplate, { type: "text/html" });
                    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob1, getFileName(e.settings));
                } else {
                    //otherwise use the iframe and save
                    //requires a blank iframe on page called txtArea1
                    txtArea1.document.open("text/html", "replace");
                    txtArea1.document.write(e.format(fullTemplate, e.ctx));
                    txtArea1.document.close();
                    txtArea1.focus();
                    sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, getFileName(e.settings));
                }

            } else {
                var blob = new Blob([e.format(fullTemplate, e.ctx)], { type: "application/vnd.ms-excel" });
                window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                link = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                a = document.createElement("a");
                a.download = getFileName(e.settings);
                a.href = link;

                document.body.appendChild(a);

                a.click();

                document.body.removeChild(a);
            }

            return true;
        }
    };

    function getFileName(settings) {
        return (settings.filename ? settings.filename : "table2excel");
    }

    // Removes all img tags
    function exclude_img(string) {
        var _patt = /(\s+alt\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"|\s+alt\s*=\s*'([^']*)')/i;
        return string.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi, function myFunction(x) {
            var res = _patt.exec(x);
            if (res !== null && res.length >= 2) {
                return res[2];
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        });
    }

    // Removes all link tags
    function exclude_links(string) {
        return string.replace(/<a[^>]*>|<\/a>/gi, "");
    }

    // Removes input params
    function exclude_inputs(string) {
        var _patt = /(\s+value\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"|\s+value\s*=\s*'([^']*)')/i;
        return string.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, function myFunction(x) {
            var res = _patt.exec(x);
            if (res !== null && res.length >= 2) {
                return res[2];
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        });
    }

    $.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
        var e = this;
        e.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(e, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
                $.data(e, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
            }
        });

        // chain jQuery functions
        return e;
    };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```